# Possible to mount multiple ActionCable cables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Is it possible to mount multiple [ActionCable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) *cables* in the same Rails application? For example as such:

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable2'
end
```

I am aware I can have multiple *channels* using the same *cable*, but I require to use **different authentication methods** for my channels. From my understanding, this is not possible using the same cable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice thought, have you tried it? What happens? Please do that -- this will most likely answer your question: simply try....

Comment: Why not move the authentication logic into the subscription request and it's handler? This way, you run only a single ActionCable server, use less TCP/IP connections per client and exert total control over subscriptions and authentication... ?

Comment: @myst, thanks for your comment. I need 2 different authentification methods, see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689243/using-actioncable-with-multiple-identification-methods . I tried for quite a bit but I have not succeeded using just one Connection.

Answer (score 4):

As elaborated in [Using ActionCable with multiple identification methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689243/using-actioncable-with-multiple-identification-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1), one approach to use different authentication methods in the same Rails app can be:

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user, :uuid

    def connect
      self.uuid = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      if env['warden'].user
        self.current_user = find_verified_user
      end
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      return User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
    end
  end
end
```

*Authenticated* channel:

```
class AuthenticatedChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    reject and return if current_user.blank?
    stream_for current_user
  end
  ...
```

*Anonymous* channel:

```
class AnonymousChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "channel_#{self.uuid}"
  end
  ...
```

Comment: This answer doesn't reply to the question. It could help, but definitely doesn't answer the question. :/

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible out-of-the-box because you can configure only one server in Rails.

In the `config/environments/development.rb` file (or what ever else environnement) you have only one `action_cable` configuration point :

```
  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]
```

Also in your layout file you can have only one `action_cable_meta_tag` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    ...

    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In order to have many cable servers, you would have to be able to configure many of them like within a `Hash` like that:

```
  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  config.action_cable = [
    {
       mount_path: nil
       url: 'wss://example.com/cable'
       allowed_request_origins: [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]
    },
    {
       mount_path: nil
       url: 'wss://example.com/cable2'
       allowed_request_origins: [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]
    }
  ]
```

And be able to set them with a `action_cable_meta_tags` (notice the plural version) helper.

## But

But Rails allows you to run your server is standalone mode, that what we are doing at my company.

So we are running a cable server with puma/unicorn and then we aren't using the `action_cable_meta_tag` tag, but we are forcing the URL to the `ActionCable.createConsumer` :

```
  const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://cable1.domain.co/cable')
  const channel = cable.subscriptions.create(...)
```

Knowing that, you can run many cable servers on many hosts or ports, and then create many `ActionCable.createConsumer` instances for each servers.

That way you have many cable servers.

I hope this would help anyone looking for running many cable servers.