# Is it possible to create two ActionCable servers in one Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

Say, I need to implement some communication between users and smart devices via websockets. The user's identifying, authorization, channels, and stuff are completely different from devices' ones, but the core models and libs are the same. That's why I would mount two ActionCable connections on the single Rails app. 
So, the code would look like this:

```
module ApplicationCableForUsers
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
    ...
  end

  class SomeChannel < ActionCable::Channel::Base; end
end
```

```
module ApplicationCableForDevices
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_device
    ...
  end

  class SomeOtherChannel < ActionCable::Channel::Base; end
end
```

```
mount ApplicationCableForUsers, to: '/ws_users'
mount ApplicationCableForDevices, to: '/ws_devices'
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: I think yout are looking for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236556/10522579)

Comment: @ray, yep, this can be handled on the channel's level, but I wouldn't like to mix users and devices logic in a single connection.

Comment: I stopped working with rails, but I imagine it's possible and you're on the right track. Other solutions would be to 1. Place your logic in a gem and import that gem in two different applications; 2. Have different modules for the user and the device logic and `include` the modules in the connection object (but not it's class) according to the login procedure; 3. Use WebSockets directly (i.e., with iodine), in which case you could use a different route (url) for each type of client (users vs. devices).